# Sum of even numbers from 1-100 using recursive function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I want to sum even numbers from 1-100 using javascript recursive function, but the output just show me 0 for odd numbers and the number itself for odd numbers

```
    function evenSum(n) {
    if (n%2 === 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (n === 100) {
        return 100;
    }
    return n + evenSum(n+1);
}
```

Comment: What do you think `if (n%2 === 1) { return 0; }` will do?

Comment: If the modulus of the number is 1 then its odd , else its even and I think it return n

Comment: got it , it stops every time and just return 0,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 if (n%2 === 1) {
    return 0;
 }
```

That will stop the recursive chain at every second number. For every odd number it will stop directly (and return 0) for every even number it will stop at the second position. Instead, you just want the recursion to continue with the next chain:

```
if (n%2 === 1) {
    return evenSum(n + 1);
}
```

Actually you can simplify (and speed up the code) if you just go to every second position:

```
function evenSum(n){
  // Stop at 100
  if(n >= 100) return 100;
  // If it starts at an odd position, go on with the next even
  if(n % 2 === 1) return evenSum(n + 1);
  // Usually just take every second step:
  return n + evenSum(n + 2);
}
```

That can be shortified to:

```
const evenSum = n => n >= 100 ? 100 : n % 2 ? evenSum(n + 1) : n + evenSum(n + 2);
```

Comment: short but takes to much stack for recursion.

Comment: @nina yes. `function evenSum(n){ let res = 0; n -= n%2 + 2; while(n <= 100) res += n+= 2; return res;}`  But the question was not about the "best" algorithms but rather asking for a fix to the current solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a recursion function which count down the values until you reach zero.

The exit condition is a check if the number is smaller or equal to zero, then return the sum otherwise decrement uneven value by one and even value by two and call the function again with the value and temporary sum.

```js
function evenSum(n, s = 0) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        return s;
    }
    return evenSum(n - (n % 2 ? 1 : 2), s + n); // tail recursion
}

console.log(evenSum(100));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function evenSum(n) {
      if (n <= 1)
          return 0;
      else
      {
          if(n%2 === 1)
              return evenSum(n - 1);
          else
              return n + evenSum(n - 1);
      }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that (works for all numbers, not just 100):

```
function evenSum(n) {
    if (n == 0) return 0; // recursive function needs to stop somewhere
    var sum = evenSum(n - 1); // recursive call
    if (n % 2 == 0) sum += n; // add current n if it's even
    return sum; // return result
}

console.log(evenSum(100));
```

Answer (score 0):

recursive sum of even number
**one line condition**

```js
function addOddToN(n) {
    return (n <= 2) ? 2 : (n%2 === 0) ? n + addOddToN(n - 1) : addOddToN(n - 1);
}

console.log( addOddToN(100) ); // 2550
console.log( addOddToN(5) ); // 6
console.log( addOddToN(4) ); // 6
console.log( addOddToN(10) ); // 30
```